# Mimic C# classes in Python

Tags: c#, python, python-2.7

I have the following **C#** public classes:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public byte var1;
    public TypeX var2;
}


public class TypeX
{
    public UInt16 num1;
    public UInt32 num2;
}
```

(Names are simplified for this example and are not real)

What would this look like in Python?  Specifically, how would `var2` be created as an instance of `TypeX`?

So far I have the come up with the following **Python** classes:

```
class ClassA():
    def __init__(self, var1, var2 = TypeX):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2


class TypeX():
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
```

However, I am nearly 100% sure this is not correct.  Should `ClassA` inherit `TypeX`?  Any guidance or explanations would be appreciated!

Comment: They aren't equivalent because you aren't assigning anything to your c# variables. You'd get a `NullReferenceException` when you attempted to access `var1` or `var2` from `ClassA`. This can be easily remedied with a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is not a statically typed language, so the answer to:

> How can I enforce var2 to be of type TypeX?

is **you don't**. Of course, you can type-check something, but the Python interpreter won't do it for you, you'll need to explicitly write this rule on your code programatically.

As to the question of how the following:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public byte var1;
    public TypeX var2;
}


public class TypeX
{
    public UInt16 num1;
    public UInt32 num2;
}
```

translates to Python, the answer is as simple as:

```
# You need to explicitly initialize the variables to their correspondent default values
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = bytes() # or b''
        self.var2 = None

class TypeX(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num1 = int() # or 0
        self.num2 = int() # or 0
```

Comment: Right, I knew Python didn't enforce types.  Thanks for the clarification on variables assignments in `__init__`.

Comment: I assume `bytes()` and `int()` typecasts whatever value is sent to `self.`...  Is it not possible to do `= TypeX()` for `var2`?  I'm guessing not, but why?

Comment: @CtrlS it’s possible indeed. But then it wouldn’t exactly match your C# code.

Comment: By the way, `bytes()` and `int()` does not type cast anything. They are exactly the same as writing `b''` and `0`

Comment: Interesting... so that's why the comments are as such.

Answer (score 2):

Python is a dynamically-typed language. The type of a variable is not determined until it is assigned a value.

The closest you can get to your C# code would be to use type hints, supported in Python 3.5+:

```
class TypeX:
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2

class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, var1, var2: TypeX):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
```

But even with type hints, the type of `var2` will not be enforced either at compilation time or at run time.

Answer (score 1):

Python is dynamically, not statically, typed, so

```
class ClassA():
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2


class TypeX():
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2
```

is a reasonable thing to do. Just pass an instance of `TypeX` in when you instantiate your `ClassA`.

However, as of Python 3.5, you can add [optional type hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), e.g.

```
class TypeX():
    def __init__(self, num1, num2):
        self.num1 = num1
        self.num2 = num2


class ClassA():
    def __init__(self, var1, var2: TypeX):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
```

This doesn't affect how the code runs (in particular it doesn't enforce the type at runtime), but it can help developers, and their tools, understand the code better.

Tools like [`mypy`](http://mypy-lang.org/) can be used to statically check your code using these optional type hints, especially if you add them to your test suite. The more hints you add, the more `mypy` can help.