# Python2.7: Initialize constructor variable as byte array

Tags: c#, python, python-2.7

I know this **C#** code:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public byte var1;
}
```

can be converted to this **Python** code:

```
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = bytes() # or b''
```

but what if `var1` were instead a *byte array* as follows:

```
public byte[] var1;
```

Normally, I would do:

```
[bytes(i) for i in myList]
```

but no such variable like `myList` exists in this case to fill that position, leaving me with `[bytes(i) for i in ]` which is obviously syntactically invalid.

Related to [Mimic C# classes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52390450/mimic-c-sharp-classes-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bytes()` is not the equivalent of a C# byte. There is no direct equivalent of a C# byte in Python; the closest would be an ordinary int. I would consider the most direct translation of that C# class to be

```
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 0
```

`bytes` objects are *immutable sequences* of bytes. If you want a mutable sequence of bytes, either a [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray-objects) or an ordinary `list` would be appropriate, or an [`array.array` array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html). I'd probably go with the list unless I had specific reason to do otherwise, really:

```
class ClassA(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = []
```

Note that `bytearray` and `bytes` represent sequences of *unsigned* bytes; their elements go from 0 to 255, not from -128 to 127. An `array.array('b')` would be a sequence of signed bytes.

Comment: What makes `0` more concise than `bytes()` or `b''`?  I am less familiar with this topic.

Comment: @CtrlS: It's not about what's more concise; it's about writing code that actually means the right thing. (`0` *is* more concise, being 1 character instead of 7 or 3, but that doesn't matter.)

Comment: Maybe concise was the wrong word...what I'm really asking I guess then is how do `bytes()` and `0` differ?

Comment: @CtrlS: `bytes()` is an immutable sequence of 0 bytes. `0` is the integer 0.

Comment: So the difference is that bytes() implies multiple bytes, whereas 0 is obviously a single value.  Okay, thanks.